# balancing a target weight using elements of a vector

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, backtracking

I'm trying to write a function called canBalance which takes as parameters an integer target weight and a Vector of integers, and returns true iff the elements of the vector can be used to "balance" the target weight (i.e. if you add the target weight to the vector, you can balance the new vector's elements). For instance, the call `canBalance(5, a1),` where `a1 = {1,4}` would return true as 5 = 1+4. Also, the call `canBalance(3, a1)` would return true as 3 + 1 = 4. However, I'm unsure how to do this. I know I should use a backtracking technique and recursion, but I'm not really sure how to translate this into code. Below is some code I've come up with so far.

```
// maybe a helper function will be useful here?

bool canBalance(int target, Vector v) {
  if (v.isEmpty()) return false;
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    // need to find some way to recurse through the vector
    //
  }
  return false; // assuming the function returns true within the for loop
}
```

Comment: Hint: change `Vector v` to `const vector<int>& v, int startIndex, int endIndex`. Or if you are comfortable with iterators, it could be `vector<int>::const_iterator start, vector<int>::const_iterator end`

Comment: @user253751 thanks!

Comment: How is this different from a) Adding `target` to the vector and b) finding a way to divide the contents of this vector into 2 groups with the same sum?

Comment: What if `target` = 0?

Comment: @ScottHunter you're right. It is no different from that. Thanks!